# Raspbia, after a reboot, wifi is only working if a ethernet cable is attached

Tags: raspbian, wifi, dhcp, wpa, wpa-supplicant

my problem is that my wifi is only getting an IP address if ethernet cable is also plugged in. I have checked many sides, but the solution below is not working. (funny thing, I have reinstalled this pi, and before this, this problem was not present)

Maybe Have you any idea how to fix this?

```
RETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
    
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ more /etc/dhcpcd.conf | grep -v \#
hostname
clientid
persistent
option rapid_commit
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
option interface_mtu
require dhcp_server_identifier
slaac private
allow-hotplug eth0  #(or with wlan0)
auto wlan0  #(or without)
interface wlan0
        static ip_address=192.168.178.99/24
        static routers=192.168.178.1
        static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

    
    
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ more /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
    ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
    update_config=1
    country=DE
    network={
            ssid="xxxxxx"
            psk="xxxxxxx"
    }
```

/edit

I have no access to the device when this problem happens

It’s plain simple direct  local lan connection

Update

so i  just have found out that the PI is getting the right ip, and my pc is getting the arp entry but the communication with the pi is not possible

Comment: You have provided no evidence; at least is `ip a; ip r`, failed to explain what is connected to what and you have put rubbish in dhcpcd.conf. Try following one of the established guides e.g. [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)
[How to set up Static IP Address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/74428/8697)

Comment: Is this a pi4 - if so, you wouldn't be the first to have this problem

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested- that problem was that the pi have even not booted without the cable

And it was caused due too a headless static ip entry
Inside cmdline.txt - which I have used right before the first boot